# Parellel configuration DCDC converter and 14 V battery

Tags: battery-charging, dc-dc-converter

I have a converter which bucks a high voltage down to 14 [V] to power some low voltage electronics. However, there should also be a battery there which is crucial during the start-up procedure and can serve as a back-up should the converter fail. The battery in question being the EarthX ETX-900 TSO 14V Aircraft Lithium Battery.

A diagram is shown below. The switch will always be closed during normal operation. Ideally, the converter should charge the battery during nominal operations. However I have the following concerns:

- I can not directly control the current flowing into the LV battery, only limit the current exiting the converter.
- The product specifies the discharge characteristic as shown below and mentions a standard charge voltage of 13.9 - 14.6. If I would set the converter channel at 13.5 V would I need extra precautions concerning overcharging the battery or would it be a self-maintaining configuration as it would start discharging when the voltage rises over 13.5?

Overall, what would your recommendations be to charge the battery during flight but still have it available during startup?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the battery have a charge controller attached?

Comment: Since the picture shows _Avionics_ as the electronics, does the converter need to be certified to meet a safety standard such as DO-254?

Comment: For context we are a student team (most of us studied Aerospace) but we are handling the certification with local authorities. The converter is an off the shelf high-end converter and is issued by a company active in aero defense. It is the brightloop DCDC-MP. As of now there is no charge controller on it, would this be possible to have on there and still be able to discharge it when necessary at any moment?